# Use macro to generate empty code for C++ class methods

Tags: c++, macros

Let's say I have a class like below:

```cpp
#define LOGGER_CLASS_ENABLED
    
#ifdef LOGGER_CLASS_ENABLED
        
class Logger{
public:
    void println(const String&);
};
    
Logger this_is_a_singleton_logger; 
    
#define MY_LOGGER this_is_a_singleton_logger
    
#endif
```

Throughout my code, whenever I want to log something, I use the following shortcut:

```cpp
MY_LOGGER.println("Hello")
```

Now, lets say I want to disable the `Logger` class. In this scenario, I don't want any logging code to be generated. So, the usual 'C-style' approach is this:

```cpp
#ifdef LOGGER_CLASS_ENABLED  
MY_LOGGER.println("Hello");
#endif
```

and repeat it for every call.

However, since there are hundreds of such calls, surrounding each print function with an extra two lines everywhere will make the code hard to read. What should I do so that I don't add two lines everywhere, keeping the only a single line of `MY_LOGGER.println("Hello")`, but make the macro replace it with empty line. Is it possible?

I tried following but it gave me an error:

```cpp
#ifndef LOGGER_CLASS_ENABLED
    
#define MY_LOGGER.println(x) // replace it with emtpiness
    
#endif
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whereas having a macro "`LOG`"

```
#if defined(LOGGER_CLASS_ENABLED)
#define LOG(msg) MY_LOGGER.println(msg) 
#else
#define LOG(msg) do {} while(false)
#endif
```

would allow to entirely disable logging (and so `msg` is not evaluated, so `LOG` argument should not have side effect).

To keep usage `MY_LOGGER.println(x)` and does "nothing" (it is still evaluate `x` though, with its side effects)
You might create a [null object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern):

```
#ifdef LOGGER_CLASS_ENABLED
    
class RealLogger
{
public:
    void println(const String& msg) { /*Real logging*/}
};

using Logger = RealLogger;

#else // !LOGGER_CLASS_ENABLED

class NullLogger
{
public:
    void println(const String&) { /*empty*/ }
};

using Logger = NullLogger;

#endif

Logger this_is_a_singleton_logger; 
#define MY_LOGGER this_is_a_singleton_logger
```

Comment: Actually I have implemented the same thing as you suggested, however since I am doing it for an embedded system with limited memory, I prefer not to generate any code at all.

Comment: Is "do {} while(false)" mandatory? Is is possible to leave it just blank?

Comment: Why would you want the overhead of creating a log message, just to ignore it?

Comment: @UserRR: Not sure of the best "empty" replacement. Most should work in basic cases. Mine and your suggestion won't compile for `decltype(LOG("test"))`. `((void)0)` seems fine/better.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: We might want the possible side effects of message. (whereas for `assert` we should not have side effect, for custom log, that rule is not necessary (even if advised IMHO)). To be safe with legacy code, we have to create log message.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe it could be useful for legacy code, but relying on side effects of a log function doesn't seem like a great design choice.

Comment: If you make the macro variadic, it allows use of templates there, like `LOG(CustomString<wchar_t, alloc>("Hello"));`. A bit of an edge-case scenario quite honestly, but nice to to have.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: I expected your answer as accepted (especially as it is that part which interest OP As I understand from comment). Your `((void)0)` is better than my `do while(false)`, and variadic is also superior... I just wanted to focus on alternative (as Adrian Mole) **if** side effect is wanted or if usage should really be `MY_LOGGER.println(x)` (which was not clear initially).

Comment: It was difficult to choose an answer because they were all good, I chose this one because it covers both macro and empty class implementation, so probably will be a good reference to others. As for me, I used variadic implementation.

Answer (score 4):

Make a macro that's conditionally no-op, like standard `assert`:

```
#ifdef LOGGER_CLASS_ENABLED
#define LOG(...) MY_LOGGER.println(__VA_ARGS__) 
#else
#define LOG(...) ((void)0)
#endif

// ...
LOG("Hello");
```

Comment: is it ok just to use #define LOG(...)    instead of #define LOG(...) ((void)0) ?

Comment: @UserRR you can do that. But I added ((void)0) as a place holder so it doesn't warn about stray semicolon. (That's also what standard assert does)

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, you can't have a macro name containing a special character, such as the dot operator.

However, depending on the complexity of your `Logger` class, you may be better off just conditionally defining 'real' and 'dummy' members of that class. Doing this may actually simplify your design; further, for the 'dummy' compilation, a decent compiler would likely optimize away all references to the `Logger` class, as it will be able to see that nothing is ever actually done by it.

Here's a possible (minimalistic) solution:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using String = std::string; // As you've used the term "String" in your code!

#define LOGGER_CLASS_ENABLED

class Logger {
public:
    #ifdef LOGGER_CLASS_ENABLED
    void println(const String& str) { std::cout << str << std::endl; }
    // ... and similar definitions for any other 'real' class functions
    #else
    void println(const String&) {}
    // ... and similar placeholder definitions for the dummy class
    #endif
};

Logger MY_LOGGER; // Note that we no longer need a conditional macro for this!

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello!" << std::endl;
    MY_LOGGER.println("Logging...");
    std::cout << "Goodbye!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As you split implementation, I prefer to have 2 classes : the real, and a [null object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern) (as in my answer) and a `using` to select the appropriate. To follow your "direction", I would prefer then an unique implementation with `#if` inside.

Comment: @Jarod42 I was considering adding the 2 class solution as an option, but then I saw your answer already addressed that (we posted about the same time). Yours is more versatile, for sure, especially if the `Logger` class definition is not in the OP's control.

Comment: `void println(const String& str) {
#ifdef LOGGER_CLASS_ENABLED
std::cout << str << std::endl;
#endif
 }` would be more succinct.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes - but then you would need 'tricks' to avoid compiler warnings about unused arguments (for the dummy compile). :-) Also, I would personally prefer to have all the dummy member definitions (assuming there are more than one) in a single, easy-to-spot, block.

Comment: `[[maybe_unused]]` might help.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but as I commented on the other answer, I was using the same approach as you mentioned, but was looking for a way not that doesn't generate code all.

Comment: @UserRR a call to `void println(const String&) {}` doesn't generate _code_. Source text isn't machine code, there is no direct connection between source text and program code. Source text is a document that describes program's function.

Comment: and one can even avoid using `ifdef` in class definition (it's considered faux pas because of possible ODR breach). You simply can have a template specialized with and without functionality, which concrete instance will be used would be based on value of a constant. They are considered separate types, so program may contain units which use both without causing an UB

Answer (score 2):

Macrodefinition is a replaceable token -- identifier. `MY_LOGGER.println(x)` is a sequence of tokens and cannot be a name of macrodefinition. You have to use a functional macro, e.g. variadic one:

```
#define LOG_PRINT(...)  MY_LOGGER.println(__VA_ARGS__)
```

`__VA_ARGS__` is a built-in macro which would be replaced by arguments given in stead of ellipsis.  At this point in C++ you might as well use variadic template functions if feature is available.

A more problematic case is when your logger uses chaining operator<< (in STL style). In that case you should have an alternative inline-able definition of logger class which does nothing and where all << will become no-ops.

Comment: Thank you very much. I followed this approach.